# Alamofire use configurable Caching

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire 5 and have the requirement that some GET-requests should be cached. If the data is older then 20 minutes the real API should be hit.

What I found is to use the ResponseCacher. But I do not see a way to configure the individual request and need some advice.

```
let responseCacher = ResponseCacher(behavior: .modify { _, response in
          let userInfo = ["date": Date()]
          return CachedURLResponse(
            response: response.response,
            data: response.data,
            userInfo: userInfo,
            storagePolicy: .allowed)
        })
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default

private override init() {
   configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
        configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadRevalidatingCacheData
   Session(
      configuration: configuration,
      serverTrustManager: ServerTrustManager(evaluators: evaluators),
      cachedResponseHandler: responseCacher
   )
```

Comment: Your use case may be implemented with actual zero code on the client side utilising a local URL cache and following the HTTP protocol, if the semantics of the "freshness" of returned data can be specified on the backend, and the backend sends corresponding response headers. This is usually the case and also strongly recommended to do so, instead implementing any custom cache logic on the client side. If you need more help with this, I am happy to go into more detail in an answer.

Comment: Yes - I would be very interested how a proper implementation can be done with ResponseCacher or whatever is needed. I was asked to create a CoreData db and cache the data there but I think that's not the way to go as you also write.

Comment: You can implement "offline" support in your app based on URL caches combined with some background "pre-fetch" feature which populates the URL cache. We have done this in our app and it works pretty well. You can of course use CoreData to cache your data. The decision whether you want to use URLCaches or rather CoreData certainly depends on a couple other requirements. Regarding caching, HTTP caching is very powerful, and it is (almost) for free, since implemented in URLSession and backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on Jon's answer, the easiest way to achieve what you want is to just let the backend *declare* the cache semantics of this endpoint, then ensure that on the client side, URLSession uses a URLCache (which is probably the default anyway) and let URLSession and the backend do the rest. **This requires, that you have control over the backend, though!**

The more elaborate answer:

Here is just an example, how a server may return a response with declared cache semantics:

```
URL: https://www.example.com/ Status Code: 200
    Age: 238645
    Cache-Control: max-age=604800
    Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 18:43:58 GMT
    Etag: "3147526947"
    Expires: Tue, 19 Jan 2021 18:43:58 GMT
    Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    x-cache: HIT

    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    Content-Length: 648
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Server: ECS (dcb/7EC7)
```

This server literally outputs the full range of what a server can declare regarding caching. The first eight headers (from `Age` to `x-cache`) declare the caching.

`Cache-Control: max-age=604800` for example declares, that the data's *freshness* equals 604800 seconds. Having the date when the server created the data, the client can now check if the data is still "fresh".

`Expires: Tue, 19 Jan 2021 18:43:58 GMT` means the exact same thing, it declares *when* the data is outdated specifying the wall clock. This is redundant with the above declaration, but it is very clearly defined in the HTTP how clients should treat this.

Having an `Age` header is a hint, that the response has been actually delivered from a cache that exists between the client and the origin server. The `age` is the estimation of this data's age - the duration from when it has been created on the origin and when it has been delivered.

I don't wont to go into detail what every header means exactly and how a client and server should behave according HTTP since this is a very intense topic, but what *you* have to do is basically when you define an endpoint, is just to *define the duration of the "freshness" of the returned data*.

The whole details: [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234)

Once you came up with a good duration, Web-application frameworks (like Rails, SpringBoot, etc.) give great help with declaring cache semantics out of the box. Then Web-application frameworks will output the corresponding headers in the response - more or less "automagically".

The URLSession will automatically do the right thing according the HTTP protocol (well, almost). That is, it will store the response in the cache and when you perform a subsequent request it first looks for a suitable response in the cache and return that response if the "freshness" of the data is still given.

If that cached data is too old (according the given response headers and the current data and time), it will try to get a fresh data by sending the request to the origin server. Any upstream cache or eventually the origin server may then return fresh data. Your URLSession data task does all this transparently without giving you a clue whether the data comes from the cache or the origin server. And honestly, in most cases you don't need to know it.

Declaring the cache semantics according HTTP is very powerful and it usually should suit your needs. Also, the client may tailor its needs with specifying certain request headers, for example allowing to return even outdated data or ignoring any cached values, and much more.

Every detail may deserve a dedicated question and answer on SO.

Answer (score 1):

If the backend is returning proper caching headers that you want to limit to a certain amount of time, adding a `Cache-Control: max-age=` header on the request may work.

If the backend isn't return proper caching headers, using `ResponseCacher` is the way to go. You would modify the `CachedURLResponse`'s `response` to include the proper `Cache-Control` header.